# What happens when moving BTC from one wallet to another on blockchain.info with 0 fee?

Tags: blockchain.info, movecmd

i just tried to move some btc between wallets on blockchain.info with 0 fees and I'm getting this: http://prntscr.com/2bmay9  --- it shows 0 btc but says its moved. what happen here? its been over 24 hours already.

Comment: you transfered 0 BTC?

Comment: no i transfered 0.8 btc .. unless it was an error because i dont know why its showing 0 btc.

Comment: Can you give us the full hash? Only a partial hash is visible in the screenshot.

Comment: when i click on the hash link it brings me here: https://blockchain.info/tx/bd13231efa1d21f58aba6d34b4a70812df8bc2fe3c58ba951680deab5628dd6a   ... thanks david

Answer (score 1):

You moved 0.8 BTC from 1DbYDYkehPSFrg9zwHY93ZcqmwFLQggw81 back to 1DbYDYkehPSFrg9zwHY93ZcqmwFLQggw81. So in essence, you didn't really move anything.

Comment: ok thanks, but its really confusing to read that page (https://blockchain.info/tx/bd13231efa1d21f58aba6d34b4a70812df8bc2fe3c58ba951680deab5628dd6a) as I dont really understand whats happening there. From what it looks like, its 4 addresses on the left thats going into 2 addresses on the right. But if its just getting moved into the same address why is there 4 on the left? should it just show that 1 address just sending to itself?

Answer (score 0):

You made an error or blockchain had a glitch. You tried to move 0 Bitcoins from your account so of course nothing is going to show up in the other account. Are your Bitcoins still showing in the account that you sent them from?